# AppEngine Approach to storing large blocks of text

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We are building an app that stores user-submitted (large blocks > 2Mb) text with AppEngine and py 2.7 runtime. As we started testing with larger text blocks, we are seeing a huge spike of data store errors in the logs. We read through the limits of datastore and saw that at most requests to it can be 1Mb. So, we are faced with perhaps (mis)using the blobstore to store the text. Using the BlobKey property type in a parent object has the limitation that it's very likely that any one user submission will have more than one block of text.

The incoming data payload comes in looking something like this:

```
{
 "name": "blah name",
 "date": "00/00/00",
 "flags": "public",
 "attachments" : [
 {"id":1,"contents":"SEDFWEWETWT$WTWEFWEFWEFWEFW ... 2Mb"},
 {"id":2,"contents":"SEDFWEWETWT$WTWEFWEFWEFWEFW ... 1Mb"}     
] 
}
```

So, how can we address this issue? Blobstore each of the attachments and then store each of the blobkeys in a list property inside the parent entity? Your suggestions and help are much appreciated.

Comment: How compressible is the contents of the large text blocks ?  Will they still be > 1MB ?

Comment: They're ASCII text, but yes, even if we could get away with that for a bit, eventually someone would post a wall of text that would push it over the limit. Just curious though, what libraries available in appengine would you use to compress the corpus?

Comment: You already answered your own question: yes, you should store it into blobstore and save the reference to blob.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is cloud storage.

[Have a look here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview)

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview